# How to output files from Dockerfile CMD to local file directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker image that reproduces a research manuscript within a reproducible environment. The end state is someone can download the image (or build it with the Dockerfile), run the container, the reproduced manuscript (and associated graphics, etc) are saved onto the local filesystem at a specified location, and the container stops.

There should be no interaction with the container.

What is the accepted way to accomplish something like this? I assume the `CMD` command is necessary to perform some action when the container is opened, but I can't figure out how to move it to the local host filesystem. Is it possible to specify where output files from a container should go with the `docker run` command?

```
FROM ghcr.io/base/package:v1.3

# Mount local directory into container
ADD . /repo

RUN quarto render repo/manuscript/manuscript.qmd
```

Comment: `RUN` is for instructions that you want to run during the build. `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are instead used at docker container run time. You can certainly specify these to write something to disk, however obviously this will require you to mount the required directory at docker run time

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not knowing how the application works it basicly boils down to these simple steps:

1. Create & build a docker file
2. Make sure the application you're running works within the docker environment
3. While spinning up  your docker container mount the local folder on the host to the folder within the container. (achieved by using `-v` argument
4. Wait for container to finish
5. Profit: Results are at the mounted folder.

So for example mounting the path `/home/user/some_folder` into a Nginx container on path `/app` can be done by using the `-v` parameter:

```
docker run -d -it --name devtest -v /home/user/some_folder:/app nginx:latest
```

This will now bind the folder `/home/user/some_folder` into the container on path `/app`

To find out more about mounting i'd refer to the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/